# Coefficient of variation of an hyperexponential

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

This question is on my mind for days and I haven't find the answer. Can someone help me?

Suppose there exists a super awesome hyperexponential random variable $X$ with $k$ exponential variables with parameters $p_1, p_2, ..., p_k$ and means $\mu_1, \mu_2, ... \mu_k$ where $p_1, ..., p_k$ are the probabilities for the exponential variables with rates respectively $\frac{1}{\mu_1}, ... \frac{1}{\mu_k}$. Let $c_X$ be the coefficient of variation for $X$ with $c_X = \frac{\sigma(X)}{E(X)}$ with $\sigma(X)=\sqrt{E(X^2)-E(X)^2}$. I want to prove that $c_X \ge 1$.

Lets just start and see what happens. $c_X \ge 1 \Leftrightarrow \frac{\sqrt{E(X^2)-E(X)^2}}{E(X)} \ge 1 \Leftrightarrow E(X^2) \ge 2 \cdot E(X)^2$. For the hyperexponential, we know that $E(X)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} \frac{p_i}{\mu_i}$ and $E(X^2)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^k \frac{2 \cdot p_i}{\mu_i}$. So if we can prove $\sum\limits_{i=1}^k \frac{2 \cdot p_i}{\mu_i^2} \ge 2 \cdot (\sum\limits_{i=1}^k \frac{p_i}{\mu_i})^2$ then we are done. I can not get this to work. I even tried partial derivatives of each of the $p_i$s, and I tried to expand the squared term. But nope, nothing worked. I even tried a prove on induction on $k$, but I can\'t get rid of the squared term.

Answer (score 0):

The inequality $2 \cdot (\sum\limits_{i=1}^k \frac{p_i}{\mu_i})^2 \le 2 \cdot \sum\limits_{i=1}^k \frac{p_i^2}{\mu_i^2} $ is not always true.

For example: $(a+b)^2 \le a^2+b^2$ if a or b is smaller than zero (not both).
For nonnegative a and b, $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2 \geq a^2+b^2$
 I think in your case $a$ and $b$ are nonnegative.
The second inequality is true, but it doesn't help when the first one is not true.

Answer (score 0):

You want to prove that $$\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{p_i}{\mu_i^2}\geq\left(\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{p_i}{\mu_i}\right)^2,$$ which follows By Jensen's inequality applied to the r.v. that equals $\mu_i$ with probability $p_i$, and the (convex) function $\phi(x)=x^2$.